# unwrapping SKPhysicsBody doesn't work

Tags: sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, forced-unwrapping

In my project, I create new nodes using a class called RocketMaker.  Inside this class, I have a function called `applyRecurringForce()`...

```
func applyRecurringForce() {
    var thrust: CGVector = CGVectorMake(100, 100)
    physicsBody!.applyForce(thrust)
}
```

My problem is I cannot access this function from the main scene.

```
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    for rocketNode in rocketShips.children {
        println("physicsBody: \(rocketNode.physicsBody.description)")
        rocketNode.physicsBody.applyRecurringForce()
    }
}
```

Starting with the above code, I get two errors, one for the `println`, and one for the call to `applyRecurringForce()`.

**Approach 1**: No forced unwrapping...
1) The println error is "Value of optional type 'SKPhysiceBody' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?" and proposes I force unwrap
2) The call returns "Cannot invoke 'applyRecurringForce' with no arguments"

**Approach2**: I add "!" following the suggested solution...
1) The println error is the same as for the previous approach": "Value of optional type 'SKPhysiceBody' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?" and again it proposes I force unwrap
2) The call returns the same error as previously: "Cannot invoke 'applyRecurringForce' with no arguments"

**Approach3**: So I follow the chain, using "physicsBody!!" in both lines in the override function.  This time, one of the two errors is removed...
1) The println error is gone
2) The call returns "'SKPhysicsBody does not have a member named 'applyRecurringForce'"

If I comment out the call, I get

> physicsNodeName:  type: representedObject:[ name:'rocket1' position:{56, 294} accumulatedFrame:{{16.849998474121094, 280.20001220703125}, {78.300003051757812, 27.5999755859375}}]

Does anyone have an idea what's up?? This double-unwrapping looks very strange to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your `applyRecurringForce` method is declared in your custom node class (`RocketMaker`), not the `SKPhysicsBody` class. So you need to change the inside of your for-loop to this:

```
println("physicsBody: \(rocketNode.physicsBody!.description)")
rocketNode.applyRecurringForce()
```

Also i'm not really sure what `rocketShips` is. I originally though it was an array but given that you are accessing the `children` property i'm going to assume it is some kind of `SKNode`. Usually you don't want to name a single node plural.

Assuming that `rocketShips` is a node, then you will need to cast its children to your custom node class because by default `children` is an array of `AnyObject` (which is why you see the double unwrapping). See below for full solution. Do note though that i'm casting the entire `children` array. If your array contains a mix of `RocketMaster` nodes and other nodes you will need to cast each child separately.

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var rocketShips: SKNode! //var rocketShips: [RocketMaster] = []
    override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
        for rocketNode in rocketShips.children as! [RocketMaster] {
            println("physicsBody: \(rocketNode.physicsBody!.description)")
            rocketNode.applyRecurringForce()
        }
    }
}

class RocketMaster: SKNode {
    func applyRecurringForce() {
        var thrust: CGVector = CGVectorMake(100, 100)
        physicsBody!.applyForce(thrust)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks loads!  You're right, rocketShips is a SKNode.  Its children are built up in the custom node class (different-colored rocket levels).  I'd tried rocketNode.applyRecurringForce() as well but was blocked by the error "AnyObject does not have member named 'applyRecurringForce()'".  Casting rocketShips children to RocketMaster solved the problem!

Comment: @ShaneO'Seasnain Please mark my answer as accepted if you feel your problem is resolved. Good luck with your game.